# Handel custom header in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless, request-headers

I have used API gateway to build business logic for my app that invokes the lambda function. For security assurance, I have generated a VAT report of the base URL of API from my cyber security expert. A total of 9 Vulnerabilities have been detected including Four Medium, three low-level, and two informational-level vulnerabilities have been identified.

1. (CSP) Wild Card Directive
2. Content Security Policy (CSP) Header Not Set
3. Cross-Domain Misconfiguration
4. Missing Anti-clickjacking Header
5. Server Leaks Information via “X-Powered-By” HTTP Response Header Field(s)
6. Timestamp Disclosure – Unix
7. X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing
8. Charset Mismatch
9. Re-examine Cache Directives
   how can remove these all Vulnerabilities?
   is there a need to set or define custom headers? ( if yes then where and how I can do that, either be in API Gateway console  or lambda script or in my client or app side code where this API Gateway base URL is invoking ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to integrate with AWS WAF for protecting your APIs against common web exploits.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-control-access-aws-waf.html

irt custom headers: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/custom-headers-api-gateway-lambda/